# Android file storage

Tags: java, android

I have a zip file in assets. On first run of app, zip file (all files and folders) gets unzipped and stored in internal storage area. The base unzipped path is  `getFilesDir()`. Since zip also contains folders, i could not use `openFileOutput` as it gave an error, contains a path separator. So i have used `FileOutputStream` instead which is now working fine. Since `FileOutputStream` does not expect private flag. Are these unzipped files and folders are private to my app or can they be accessed from other apps?

Here's the code,

```
`public boolean unpackZip(InputStream is, String path) throws IOException {
        String filename;
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
        ZipEntry ze;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;
```

`` while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        filename = ze.getName();

        // Need to create directories if not exists, or
        // it will generate an Exception...
        if (ze.isDirectory()) {
            File fmd = new File(path + filename);
            fmd.mkdirs();
            continue;
        }

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);

        while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        fout.close();
        zis.closeEntry();
    }

    zis.close();
    return true;
}` ``

Comment: dr share yr code.

Comment: There was no need to show code. getFilesDir() is internal private memory for your app only.